# Cohomology with compact support for sheaves in separated schemes of finite type over a Noetherian scheme: three different definitions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, duality-theorems, sheaf-cohomology, etale-cohomology

usually there are three notions of cohomology with compact (proper) support. The first one usually done in the étale site. However the second one is used in Verdier duality. The third one is done in algebraic topology.

Let $X$ be a separated scheme of finite type over a Noetherian scheme $S$. Then Nagata compactification guarantees an open immersion $j : X \hookrightarrow \overline{X}$. In this context, the cohomology with compact support can be defined as $\text{H}^q (X, \mathscr{F}) = \text{H}_c^q (\overline{X}, j_{!}\mathscr{F})$. In this case, $R^{p}\text{H}_c^0 \neq \text{H}_c^{p}$.

In the other approach, $\text{H}_c^{q} (X, \mathscr{F})$
 is defined as the $q$-th right derived functor of the proper supported global sections.

In the third approach, $\text{H}_c^{q} (X, \mathscr{F})$
 is defined as the $q$-th right derived functor of the compact supported global sections.

What's is the relation between these three approaches? Why the first one is used in étale cohomology? Would Verdier duality holds in the first and third approach? Why the first and second approach is called compact supported anyway (I can't see the sections that are compact supported!)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question! What does $H^0_c$ mean on the etale site? You can't define it literally to be compactly supported sections of course. Similar question for proper supported global sections. Is it somehow the sections which come from pushforwards of proper things? If, by chance, you don't know the anwer (it's unclear from your question), perhaps this is why we use shriek-forward to proper things!

Comment: @AlexYoucis Why this does not make sense? Interpreting sections as functions on the étale coverings by composing with the étale morphism and computing the support seems reasonable. My point is why the one using compactifiable morphisms called compactly supported anyway? I can´t see compactly supported sections, so what´s the idea behind this. Certainly, the name is not a mere coincidence.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I mean sections can be though as functions with values on the stalk (and domain some étale covering), so compactness and properness are defined in the usual way.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is the difference between the last two, so I will assume that this is the same thing. The thing is, in topology (at least for reasonable spaces) the first and the second/third definition agree. Moreover, in the context of étale sheaves, the comparison theorem implies that $H_{c,et}(X_{\overline{k}},\Lambda)=H_c(X(\mathbb{C}),\Lambda)$, hence that cohomology class in the first (and only) definition of $H_c$ in the étale context "could be" compactly supported in $H_c(X(\mathbb{C}))$.

Comment: However, as Alex Youcis said, you cannot expect that compactly supported sections give interesting result in algebraic geometry : the only proper subset of an affine variety over a field are the finite ones...

Comment: @user113969 The compactly supported sections are the ones such that the support is compact, while the proper sections are the ones such that the support is proper as a closed subscheme (separated universally closed of finite type). As I said, my third definition and the second one makes some sense for me, however the first one seems quite weird to be called compactly supported.

Comment: @user40276 But, if $X$ is Noetherian EVERY subset is compact. So, every section is 'compactly supported'. Similarly, what do you mean that the support of $\mathcal{F}$ is proper? If you don't assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent, then why is the support closed? What structure are you taking, the reduced structure? This seems more contrived than using the first definition.

Comment: @user40276 There is a relative version of cohomology with compact support, namely the sheaves $R^if_!$, or better, the complexes $Rf_!$. If $f$ is a map to a point, $R^if_!\mathcal{F}$ are just the abelian groups $H^i_c(X,\mathcal{F})$. The fundamental properties $Rf_!$ are $Rf_!=Rf_*$ if $f$ is proper and $R(f\circ g)_!=Rf_!\circ Rg_!$. Now if $j:X\rightarrow \overline{X}$ and $f:\overline{X}\rightarrow pt$ the map to the point, then $H^*_c(X,\mathcal{F})=H^*(R(f\circ j)_!\mathcal{F})=H^*(Rf_*j_!\mathcal{F})=H^*(\overline{X},j_!\mathcal{F})$

Comment: @user113969 Thanks! I think this justify the name. But what does $H*_c$ mean? And what's the underlying site (étale, Zariski or etc)?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Well, I'm always thinning about quasi-coherent sheaves.  By the support proper I mean as a closed subscheme with the reduced structure. My intention is to copy the usual sheaf cohomology (and singular cohomology) with compact support in topological spaces, but maybe my definitions are going in the wrong direction…

Comment: @user40276 I was thinking of several context at the same time. The functors $f_!$ are defined for instance in Iversen in the topological context. In the étale context, the only way to define $H^*_c$ is to define $f_!$ first. But it doesn't change what I said. About quasi-coherent sheaves (note that $f_!$ does not preserve quasi-coherence in general), you will have to define through the first definition and forget about the others (too much compact subset, too few proper ones), but you can still call it $H^*_c$ because it is defined similarly and shares the same functorial properties.

Comment: @user113969 Could you expand about these similarities ans functorial properties you said? Maybe, if you want, you can post this (adding your other comments) as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a longer version of my previous comments.

In topology, along with the ordinary cohomology, there is also the so called cohomology with compact support, denoted by $H_c^*(X)$. It can be defined

- using compactly supported differential forms
- using singular cochains that vanish outside a compact set
- using the derived functor of the compactly supported global sections of a sheaf.

all of them give the same result (with corresponding coefficients) for reasonable spaces and have the following fundamental properties :

- they coincide with ordinary cohomology if $X$ is compact.
- they are covariant wrt open immersion and contravariant wrt to proper maps.
- there exists localization long exact sequence : if $U\subset X$ is an open subset and $Z$ the closed complement, the sequence :
  $$ \dots\rightarrow H^*_c(U)\rightarrow H^*_c(X)\rightarrow H_c^*(Z)\rightarrow H^{*+1}_c(U)\rightarrow\dots$$
  is exact.

Lets talk about sheaves now. Along with the compactly supported global sections functor $\Gamma_c(X,\cdot)$, there exists a relative version, namely the functor $f_!$ for $f:X\rightarrow Y$. It is defined as 
$$f_!\mathcal{F}(U)=\{ s\in\mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(U)), \text{such that } f_{|\mathrm{supp} (s)}:\mathrm{supp}(s)\rightarrow Y \text{ is proper}\} $$
and as the following properties : $(f\circ g)_!=f_!\circ g_!$, for $j$ an open immersion, $j_!$ is the extension by zero functor and is exact, $f_!=f_*$ if $f$ is proper, and for any $y\in Y$
$$(f_!\mathcal{F})_y=H^*_c(f^{-1}(y),\mathcal{F})$$
When $f:X\rightarrow pt$, you get the functor $\Gamma_c$.

In topology, and only in topology, because of the so called soft sheaves, deriving $f_!$ et $\Gamma_c$ makes sense and give the expected cohomology. I believe this justify the name.

In other context, like in algebraic geometry, there are not enough proper subset or there are too much compact ones to have interesting results. Besides, in the context of étale cohomology (which was developed in order to have a cohomology theory like the singular one), the only definition that would make sense is something that can be compared to the topological cohomology with compact support. Hence your second and third definitions cannot be used.

However, the first make perfect sense : the functor $j_!$ exists, this is the left adjoint of $j^*$ for an open immersion, the so called extension by zero functor. So that, for $f:X\rightarrow Y$ we can define $f_!$ to be $\overline{f}_*\circ j_!$ where $j:X\rightarrow \overline{X}$ is any compactification with $f=\overline{f}\circ j$ and $\overline{f}:\overline{X}\rightarrow Y$ proper. Similarly, we can define $\Gamma_c$ to be $\Gamma\circ j_!$.

It turns out, that their derived functors are not interesting, but $R^i\overline{f}_*j_!$ and $R^i\Gamma\circ j_!$ are and are exactly what we wanted :

- they can be compared to the topological ones
- they are covariant wrt to open immersion, contravariant wrt proper morphisms
- there are localization long exact sequences.